# Selenium: is there a way to check if text extends beyond the borders of an element?

Tags: python, html, jquery, css, selenium

I'm writing tests python+selenium, and here is the problem I've stumbled upon.
I need to check if the text in a box is displayed correctly and doesn't go beyond the margins.
What I means is:
[image: Text needs to fit the box]

Page source:

```
<div class="mt-5">
            <div class="row flex-column flex-lg-row">
                <div id="card-6e64c570-f558-47c8-d66a-08d9a43db45b" class="events-left-block w-100 col-lg-6 mb-4xl position-relative">
                    <a href="/Invite/Trainings/6e64c570-f558-47c8-d66a-08d9a43db45b?back=%2FCatalog" class="w-100">
                        <div class="card border-0 bg-white h-100 shadow rounded-lg p-0">
                            <div class="card-body p-4 h-100 d-flex flex-column">
                                <div class="card-title text-dark mb-4 row justify-content-between no-gutters flex-nowrap">
                                    <h5 class="mb-0">Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis</h5>
                                    <span class="text-white ml-4"></span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="card-text d-flex justify-content-between align-items-end flex-row flex-grow-1">
                                    <ui class="list-group-flush">
                                        <li class="d-flex align-items-center small list-group-item li-info text-dark">
                                            <i class="fas fa-user-friends text-light-gray fa-small"></i>
                                            1
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="d-flex align-items-center list-group-item small li-info text-dark">
                                            <i class="ri-calendar-fill text-light-gray small"></i>
                                            29.11.2021
                                        </li>
                                    </ui>
                                    <img class="rounded-circle cover-image" src="/images/default-training.png" width="64" height="64" alt="img">
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>                
            </div>
    </div>
```

I was wondering if there is a way to check (by selenium, jquery, whatever) if the text fits the box?

Comment: Do you want to check if it's to long or are you looking for a solution to crop it?

Comment: Check if it's too long will be enough for me @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: Please consider adding `[html]` or `[css]` tag to your question as it is related to these technologies

Comment: @organiccotton This should be a bug in the application. You can report it. Ideally, there should be a limit of characters which a text box can accept. If it goes beyond that, then a proper validation error should come. That can be your automation scenario. Second, if still you need to automate this bug with selenium, then you can use visual automation.  Enter the characters and take a screenshot. Then compare it with correct behavior.

Comment: @QualityMatters thank you! Yeah, I know that it's a bug, I'm looking for a way to automate checks like this..